# How to get Original Long values from already exceeded MaxValue(2147483647) in intValue in Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

In My iOS app earlier we have used bellow line of code to get the ID Value an object

```
 NSNumber * newObjID = @([responceData[@"id"] intValue]);
```

Now the problem is, the "id" getting from serve is exceeded the **MAX_INT_VALUE (2147483647)**

So that now the values getting in newObjID are some wired negative values like

**-2138406908 but it is supposed to be 2156560388**

We have fixed this by changing the above line to as bellow with the `longLongValue instead of intValue`

```
 NSNumber * newObjID = @([responceData[@"id"] longLongValue]);
```

Still there is a problem exists for the **already saved Records**,

Now we need to change the already wrongly saved values ID to the actual ID's

**Is there any change to convert that wrong -Negative values to Actual long values**

like I want to print newObjID = 2156560388 if the newObjID = -2138406908

Please help

Comment: You could try `@([responceData[@"id"] unsignedIntValue]);`

Comment: Should work, see my answer.

Comment: @skaak, thank you bro, Accepted your answer and is working fine... thanks for your quick help bro

Comment: Thanks glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unsigned int`.

This

```
        int i = -2138406908;
        unsigned int j = 2156560388;
        
        if ( i == j )
        {
            NSLog(@"Same");
        }
```

will print `Same`. So I think it should be possible, it is just a question of formatting. Maybe you need to do it like this

```
        int oldId = -2138406908; // Your old negative ID goes here
        long newId = ( unsigned int ) oldId; // Note the conversion through unsigned int
        NSNumber * newIdNumber = @(newId); // This is to make it a NSNumber

        NSLog(@"New ID is %lu or %@", newId, newIdNumber ); // Prints OK
```